# product aggregates in clingo

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

In clingo you can use aggregates, such as `#min`, `#max` and `#sum`. I assume there is no aggregate for products, so how would I implement a product for varying number of atoms? Preferably without introducing aux predicates. Example:

```
total(1,4).
total(2,8).
total(3,9).
```

I'm searching for a functionality which outputs `288`, since `4*8*9 = 288`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is the following, but it uses auxiliary predicates. Maybe it can be improved...

```
total(1,4).
total(2,8).
total(3,9).

n(1..N-2):- N = #count{K : total(K,_)}.

prod(0,P):- total(1,P0), total(2,P1), P = P0*P1.
prod(N,P):- n(N), prod(N-1,P0), total(N+2,P1), P = P0*P1.
```

yielding

```
total(1,4) total(2,8) total(3,9) n(1) prod(0,32) prod(1,288)
```